# Can closed questions be automatically tagged as 'closed'?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

Mainly so I can add 'closed' as an ignored topic in my prefs and hide them from the page. It's very frustrating to see tons of closed questions all over the place.

Comment: Closed questions can be weeded out with the search constraint `closed:no`, so perhaps the feature to ask for would be a way to add a search constraint to whatever generates your front page.

Comment: @Blrfl Surely tag filtering *is* a search constraint. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: For starters, it would duplicate the existing open/closed attribute.  For seconds, SO would have to add special-case code to make the tag and attribute mirror each other and prevent users from opening/closing questions by editing the tags.  For thirds, being able to apply the other available search constraints to the front page is useful for other things, ergo more bang for the modification buck.

Answer (score 1):

No.

For the reasons why, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: I don't see how those arguments apply. A closed question can definitely be described with one tag: Closed, and I think it'd be be quite difficult for someone to misinterpret what Closed means... it's even appended to the title of the question when it's closed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [closed:0 search](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3a0%20is%3aquestion) to filter them out.  Unfortunately, this doesn't look as nice since they added answers to search results.